# Is it possible to run Python without installation (without using packagers like py2exe)?

Tags: python, dll, installation, python-standalone

We have a complex tool (coded in Python) for environment validation and configuration. It runs on various Windows flavors. We used this tool within the company so far. However now we want our support engineers to use it on the road. The problem is they will not have permissions to install Python in customer machines.

To address this situation, we looked at utilities like py2exe, cx_freeze and pyInstaller. While they are good, the generated EXE runs into dependency issues in some situations. So we dropped using these tools.

Is it possible to take all python related files in a pen drive and run it directly from it? When we do that, obviously the interpreter complains because the DLLs are not registered on the target machine. I suspect just registering the DLLs may lead to other problems. Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: Which dlls need to be registered ?

Comment: python27.dll is where it started

Comment: Running WinPython on a USB-stick should work, doesn't it? For sure, you have to be careful with paths etc., since there won't be any environment variables.

Comment: WInPython could be a solution. However our application does not run out of the box since it uses PyGtk. I did not find an easy way to get PyGtk with WinPython. Another issue is WinPython targets scientific computing and has a large set of libraries which we may not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your script is `main.py`,

- copy all the contents of python directory to the directory it reside in
- search `python*.dll` in your windows directory and it to `project/python`
- create `project/main.bat`:

**main.bat**

```
"%~dp0/python/python.exe" "%~dp0/main.py" %*
```

The project directory should be:

```
project
├── python
|   ├── python.exe
|   ├── python27.dll
|   └── ...
├── main.py
└── main.bat
```

Now, invoke the program with `main.bat`

Comment: I was hoping this would work! Unfortunately it does not. It gives the same error as before. The python DLL is still not registered with Windows.

Comment: Find `python*.dll` in your windows directory and copy it to `project/python` directory.

Comment: Awesome, I got it working! Thanks @napuzba.

For others who want to try this: note that python27.dll is not in the installation folder but in **C:\Windows\System32**.